# Replace all links in a text file except these that contain certain value

Tags: regex, notepad++

I am trying to replace these links:

```
<a href="https://facebook.com/98347545/345">text</a>
<a href="https://google.com/search/98345">text</a>
<a href="https://instagram.com/34543/68/"></a>
<a href="https://google.com/image/83454.jpg">text</a>
<a href="https://reddit.com/ftr9343/">text</a>
```

in Notepad++ using regex except these that contain **google.com/***

So the final result should be:

```
<a href="https://mynewlink.com/123/">text</a>
<a href="https://google.com/search/98345">text</a>
<a href="https://mynewlink.com/123/"></a>
<a href="https://google.com/image/83454.jpg">text</a>
<a href="https://mynewlink.com/123/">text</a>
```

I can replace all my links with a single link with:

Find what: `(href=".*?")`
Replace with: `href="https://mynewlink.com/123/"`

but I don't know how to exclude these containing **google.com/***

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1):

You can use this for the search box:

```
href="https:\/\/(?!google\.com\/)[^"]+
```

and this for the replacement:

```
href="https://mynewlink.com/123/
```

Comment: This works perfectly! Thank you.